# Different length of list item when its created dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made e a list of input (type = file) fields where the number of input fields can be dynamically altered by adding or removing fields.

So the list looks like this:

```
<ol>
    <li><input type="file"><input type="text" placeholder="..."></li>
</ol>
```

See picture#1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG2dc.jpg

And when I click the '+' button a new list item is created with the same attributes but somehow it is longer than the first item which is coded in the html file.

See picture#2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5neP3.jpg

I tried Firefox and Chrome, both the same result. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Show your code that generates it. Looks like whitespace.

Comment: Can you please display your javascript function that creates your dynamic data and any relevant/related html. If we have nothing to work with we cannot tell you the problem without taking random guesses.

Comment: Thanks! yes it was a whitespace that I did not see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the fact you have a white space in the hard-coded code and the generated code you do not.

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="file"> <input type="text" placeholder="Has Space"></li>
  <li><input type="file"><input type="text" placeholder="No Space"></li>
</ul
```

Comment: Thanks! yes it was a whitespace that I did not see